# how to change ion-content bgcolor style except card content

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi I use ionic cdn in my web page
https://vipage.vivbook.com/lianaox/

Current site doesn't have ion-content tag.

The first problem is the screen is not scroll able.
I got that it is because of I didn't use ion-content
I add ion-content but the problem is how to use this animated css to the background of the page (not background of the card!)?

```
ion-content{
        
    background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #ee7752, #e73c7e, #23a6d5, #23d5ab);
    background-size: 400% 400%;
    animation: gradient 15s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        background-position: 100% 50%;
    }
    100% {
        background-position: 0% 50%;
    }
}
```

And is there anyway to enable scrollbar without using ion-content?

Comment: anyone knows???

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Ionic 4@5.

```css
ion-content {
    --background: *whatever you want here*
}
```

Or,

```css
ion-content {
    --background: transparent;
    background: linear-gradient(*whatever you want here*);
}
```